# Safari displays Horizontal Nav as Vertical using Flexbox

Tags: html, css, safari, flexbox

**My horizontal nav bar becomes vertical in Safari.** Using flexbox to and space/size the li as the browser increases/decreases in size. It works great in Chrome and Firefox, but for some reason it becomes vertical in Safari (which makes the sticky scroll nav bar absolutely destroy any attempt at a layout).

I'm somewhat of a code noob. Made my first scratch coded [site](http://thebestmle.com) as a portfolio piece, but it doesn't work well for that if it doesn't work right on the main browsers (going for Safari, Chrome and Firefox). I've searched here for answers, but haven't found anything that works with my problem.

I checked caniuse.com (caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) and went through the bugs listed there. This is not on the list of known bugs/issues on [Github](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs). Though there was a pen (codepen.io/philipwalton/pen/NqLoNp) on Github I thought might be close. Tried using display block on .FlexItem (li in my case) before .FlexContainer (navList in my case), but that was a no go.

relevant HTML —

```
<nav>
    <ul class="navList">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="mLe_pages/mLe_PORTFOLIO.html">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="mLe_pages/mLe_ABOUT.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="mLe_pages/mLe_BLOG.html">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="mLe_pages/mLe_SAMPLE.html">Sample</a></li>
        <li><a href="mLe_pages/mLe_PROJECT.html">Project</a></li>
        <li><a href="mLe_pages/mLe_CONTACT.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

my relevant Css —

```
.navList {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-left: 6.82%;
  padding-right: 15.91%;
  margin-bottom: 3.41%;
  height:auto;
  list-style:none;
  font-size: 3.25vw;
  text-style: bold;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: white;
}

/*divs for sticky nav bar*/
nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  z-index:500;
}
```

This is my first question on stackoverflow, so I appreciate whatever direction you all can give me. I'm trying to have the nav bar align on the left and the right with the gif used as the header (thus the randomness of the padding percentages), so I thought that flex box would be perfect for my purposes.

Thanks in advance for any help! (sorry for the random urls, I can't post more than 2 links with this low rep)

Em

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this is a case of not using all the necessary prefixes:

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/L7qaym5a/1/)

```css
.navList {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 3.41%;
  height: auto;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 2.25vw;
  text-style: bold;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="navList">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="mLe_pages/mLe_PORTFOLIO.html">Portfolio</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="mLe_pages/mLe_ABOUT.html">About</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="mLe_pages/mLe_BLOG.html">Blog</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="mLe_pages/mLe_SAMPLE.html">Sample</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="mLe_pages/mLe_PROJECT.html">Project</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="mLe_pages/mLe_CONTACT.html">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'd felt like I was just missing something silly, and hadn't added the prefixes. You're so right on, works great now.